# Иногда сайт самостоятельно закрывает сессию

Tags: дефект

Коллеги!

Уже два раза было такое состояние, что я вошел на сайт, пишу сообщение и при попытке отправить сообщение сайт мне заявляет, что я не вошел на сайт. То есть в процессе работы что-то происходит, и моя сессия закрывается.

Меня это пока что не очень парит, так как это было всего два раза за примерно полгода или год работы. Но администрации это должно было бы быть любопытно.

Спасибо.

UPD1:

Последний раз такое было только что. Можете поглядеть в логах, что у Вас не так.

Comment: Добавлю от себя - у меня такое происход периодично раз в неделю\2, причем при попытке открыть "последние входящие сообщения" причем если вернутся обратно на сайт и обновить страницу - сессия подхватывается снова(автовход выключен).

Comment: Ни разу такого не наблюдал за всё время нахождения на сайте.

Comment: Если я авторизуются через соц сети, то также как и у автора. Если через email, то всё норм.

Comment: SO как бы говорит: "Пора отдохнуть".